# Which ayah in the Qur'an was the last to be revealed?

Tags: quran

What are the candidates (and evidences) for ayaat which are claimed to be the last one revealed? I've heard so many opinions over the years, from Ma'idah:3 to Baqarah:281 to Surat Nasr and a few more.

Answer (score 7):

There is no general conclusion on the matter. It depends, really, on who you ask.

If you go by [Sahih al-Bukhari hadith](http://sunnah.com/urn/42220):

> **Narrated Ibn `Abbas:**
>
> The last Verse (in the Qur'an) revealed to the Prophet was the Verse dealing with usury (i.e. Riba).
>
> حَدَّثَنَا قَبِيصَةُ بْنُ عُقْبَةَ، حَدَّثَنَا سُفْيَانُ، عَنْ عَاصِمٍ، عَنِ الشَّعْبِيِّ، عَنِ ابْنِ عَبَّاسٍ ـ رضى الله عنهما ـ قَالَ آخِرُ آيَةٍ نَزَلَتْ عَلَى النَّبِيِّ صلى الله عليه وسلم آيَةُ الرِّبَا‏.‏
>
> <sub>English reference: Vol. 6, Book 60, Hadith 67</sub>
>
> <sub>Arabic reference: Book 65, Hadith 4586</sub>

Of course, this does not give the exact ayah.

Another common idea of the last verse revealed is the [third ayah in surat Al-Ma'ida](http://tanzil.net/#5:3):

> Prohibited to you are dead animals, blood, the flesh of swine, and that which has been dedicated to other than Allah, and [those animals] killed by strangling or by a violent blow or by a head-long fall or by the goring of horns, and those from which a wild animal has eaten, except what you [are able to] slaughter [before its death], and those which are sacrificed on stone altars, and [prohibited is] that you seek decision through divining arrows. That is grave disobedience. This day those who disbelieve have despaired of [defeating] your religion; so fear them not, but fear Me. **This day I have perfected for you your religion and completed My favor upon you and have approved for you Islam as religion.** But whoever is forced by severe hunger with no inclination to sin - then indeed, Allah is Forgiving and Merciful.

(emphasis mine)

So as you can see, there is no general consensus on the idea of the final verse. You can see [several claims here](http://www.quranicstudies.com/quran/the-last-verse-of-the-quran/), and a somewhat logical conclusion, although it is not a scholarly conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer seems to answer the question pretty well. I'll just add one tradition which is mentioned in [Tafsir Tabari](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?idfrom=825&idto=825&bk_no=50&ID=830):

> وقـيـل: هذه الآية أيضاً آخر آية نزلت من القرآن
>
> It is said: This verse too, is the last revealed verse in the Quran.

The mentioned verse is:

> وَاتَّقُوا يَوْمًا تُرْجَعُونَ فِيهِ إِلَى اللَّهِ ۖ ثُمَّ تُوَفَّىٰ كُلُّ نَفْسٍ مَّا كَسَبَتْ وَهُمْ لَا يُظْلَمُونَ
>
> And fear a Day when you will be returned to Allah . Then every soul will be compensated for what it earned, and they will not be treated unjustly.
>
> 2:281

Comment: I wonder if the answer you are pointing at still exists!