# Finding the historical context for verses in the Qur'an

Tags: quran, source-identification

The best explanations I've read of verses from the Qur'an make reference to the time they were revealed, as these give practical examples and context for the verse. However, finding such information myself is difficult (in my experience). There are plenty of translations of the Qur'an and hadith available (online and in print), and Q&A sites like this, but is there a widely accepted way of matching hadith with verses from the Qur'an, or any tools for doing this? Or is it just a case of searching and asking on a verse by verse basis and hoping to stumble across the information?

Those tools or methods specifically available to lay people would be most helpful, as I've little to no access to a mosque or place of specialist Islamic learning nearby to ask questions on specific verses. My apologies if this is too simple a question or is tagged incorrectly.

Comment: The best way is to read the books of exegesis (tafseer). There are many available in english. Modern, and older ones translated. Part of their purpose is to explain the historical context.

Comment: @لَاإِلٰهَإِلَّاالله thank you, that's very helpful of you.

Comment: you are most welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Mekkan suras (chapters) were revealed in the first 13 years and Madenite chapters were reveled in the last 10 years. They may have been reveled in Madinah or in Mecca, after Fath (opening) Mecca.
2. In the last 2 years the messenger PBUH reordered some verses. For example the last verse of the Quran was put in 5:03.
3. There is a complete science called Asbab Al-Nuzool, causes of the revelations. 
   this science connect the Suras and verses to their occasion and circumstances. Of course the verses are not limited to these situations but it help putting date in perspective.
4. I got a wealth of information when I googled  اسباب النزول

Comment: I don't know where you got your 2nd claim from, the Prophet always used to inform his scribes where the actual revealed verses should be put in the order of the Qur'an! And the statement that verse 5:3 is the last one revealed is rather wrong it is one of 5or 6 candidates and not the one with stronger evidences. https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1715/which-ayah-in-the-quran-was-the-last-to-be-revealed