# Tafseer book mainly focused on why certain ayath were revealed

Tags: quran, revelation, order-of-revelation

Are there books—preferably in English (but if not, in Arabic)—which focus mainly on, to our best knowledge, why certain Quran ayath were revealed? (What was the context at the time they were revealed?)

Put it another way: Is there a go-to source when one is trying to find reason of the revelation of a certain ayah?

Comment: Tafseer books usually by default cover this topic. There are books that focus on the reason of revelation and I've seen this already covered on the site (see for example [Finding the historical context for verses in the qur'an](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/29600/finding-the-historical-context-for-verses-in-the-quran). The topic is usually referred to as Asbab an-Nuzul(an-Nuzool)  أسباب النزول in Arabic.

Answer (score 1):

I found Al-Wahidi's Asbab Al-Nuzul. [It is also translated to English](https://fonsvitae.com/product/al-wahidis-asbab-al-nuzul-the-great-commentaries-of-the-holy-quran-volume-iii/).